# Create table table if not exists else alter table

Tags: php, mysql, alter-table, create-table

I have a MySQL Database with a Table (Mail) which has the columns : ID, Content, Date and Title. I would like to know if there is an option to check if the table exists and if it does then alter the table for example if I want to add a column. The only possible solution I found for this was something like this:

```
$sql=mysql_query(
        "SELECT something FROM Mail");

if (!$sql){

mysql_query("ALTER TABLE Mail ADD Test VARCHAR(150) DEFAULT NULL");

}ELSE{

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE if not exists `Mail` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Content` longtext,
`Datum` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`Titel` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`Test` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ");

}
```

So I would like to know if there is a simpler way to do this and maybe even in 1 query(probably not)? If anyone knows a better/simpler way to do this it would be great!

And I know Mysql_ is deprecated but I will switch to PDO soon!

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to ALTER a non-existing table will raise an error. This will suffice:

```
$res = mysql_query('ALTER TABLE Mail...');
if (!res) {
    mysql_query('CREATE TABLE Mail...');
}
```

Or you can go even more hackish:

```
mysql_query('CREATE TABLE Mail IF NOT EXISTS...'); // does nothing if table already exists
mysql_query('ALTER TABLE Mail ADD Test...'); // does nothing if the column already exists
```

I cant refrain from mentionning that this code smells really bad. The only situation where I wouldn't recommend a severe rework of your logic is if this is only related to an automated installation/upgrade procedure.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ungly hack for this, that works quite well

- create a script, that
- - does the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...` stuff
- - does the `ALTER TABLE ...` stuff **ignoring** a resulting error
- - commits suicide by doing `file_put_contents(__FILE__,'');`
- **include it**.

On first run, it will do what has to be done, on later runs you will include an empty file. Even concurrent first runs will be no problem, as the `IF NOT EXISTS` consition is true only once, and the `ALTER TABLE` will just fail.

This provides an ugly-but-working path from either no table or the wrong version of the table to the desired version.

Comment: Thnx for the suggestion but since I've got quite a few tables this isn't really an option. I will keep it in mind though because it could come in handy sometimes!

Comment: Just to make that clear: You create one of these **per table**